# Which is best way to add a new line to a table?

Tags: tables

Here are 4 propositions about adding a line in a table (the red button):

[image: tab add line]
[image: tab add line]
[image: tab add line]
[image: tab add line]

For me, the best way is the last one with the fat add_button.

Can you make me sure it is the best way?

Comment: This isn't opinion based. An argument can be made pending location of the new row.

Comment: Where does the newly created line appear? At the top of the table, or the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on where the new row will appear. Will they always be added to the bottom? Or can they be placed in between any row?
Depending on this choice you'll have a different design.

If a row is always added to the top (or bottom), place the adding row button at the top (or at the bottom). Design 3 or 4 could qualify for that, but you should add a label with "Add row" next to the plus icon. It's less ambiguous that way.

If a row can be placed anywhere, so top, bottom or in between existing rows, you could opt for an add button next to your delete button.

[image]

In this picture the buttons are labeled edit and delete, but they could be anything, like delete and add. Sometimes you'll also see - and + (like Apple), but that is a bit vague as well since it can imply reducing or increasing the value in the table.